# Is EDU_Class a deprecated hidden teams pre-built template?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I cannot find documentation on "edu_class" and how it relates to Class Teams.
"edu_class" is not a custom template made by us, It does not appear in Teams Admin Center template.
We have teams created like this in powershell
New-Team -DisplayName 'Unit Operations Sem2 2022' -Description 'Unit Operations Sem2 2022. Test for Class-type Teams' -Template EDU_class
However, the msgraph documentation only talks about the pre-built in template educationClass.
If I try and create a "edu_class" team via msgraph on our Test environment i get
"A template with id "edu_class" and locale 'en-US' could not be found."
if I try and make a educationClass team I get
"Team with template 'educationClass' can not be provisioned using a group which does not belong to a class"
We do not use School Data Sync
A "edu_class" team looks very similar to a educationClass team
It includes the Education Team Home page.
I believe educationClass. is an evolution of "edu_class"

A web search for ms graph "edu_class" will return references to people using it but no actual information

Answer (score 0):

These are actually the same thing, just used in different ways.

"educationClass" is the [template in a Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/get-started-with-teams-templates) call, but "EDU_Class" is the [Teams PowerShell template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/new-team?view=teams-ps#parameters).

However, I also know that we are unable to [create a Class Team from a pre-existing group](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5537) at this time. I've logged a job to MS for confirmation before :(